# How to learn differentiation?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, learning

I am having a confusion in learning differentiation. Can you please point me to some video tutorials which explains differentiation basics clearly for beginners?

Comment: have you tried youtube?

Comment: @Ockham, yes I tried, but there are lot of videos right, so I am asking suggestion from experts which video is best

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend the tutorials and videos available at [**The Khan Academy**](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/calculus); very detailed, thorough, every step of the way.

The link provided will take you to "calculus" listings of topics and tutorials. They're about 10 minutes in length, each, and you can go through them at your own pace and time preference.

I believe the site also allows you to register to engage with practice problems, progress checks, etc.

***$\color{darkblue}{Caveat}$***: "Watching" math will only go so far; you need to USE what you're learning to know it inside out! So be sure to make a point of "applying" what you're learning through the video tutorials!

Comment: If I could upvote more than once, I would do so on this answer.  Watching Khan Academy videos helped me *so* much in Calc I and II. :)

Comment: @anorton: me too.

Comment: Although Khan Academy is very good for instruction purposes, it is easy to end up watching too much and differentiating to little - it is practice not instruction that makes perfect.

Comment: @Fredrik I agree whole-heartedly. Hence, I added the "caveat"!

Answer (score 4):

I might also point out that [coursera](http://www.coursera.com) currently has a [course](https://class.coursera.org/calc1-001/class/index) on introductory calculus being taught by Dr. Fowler from Ohio State University. I think he does a very good job, and he's just now getting to the idea of derivatives.

There are also discussion forums (built on a stackexchange engine) for the site too.

Answer (score 3):

Youtube.com/professorelviszap Make sure you learn the calculus rap.

Answer (score 1):

you know what... differentiation and integration is like a knife... you need to sharpen it. the same is through with you.
first, learn all the formulas and you also have to have a good foundation with algebra for the complex functions....
then solve and solve problems... spend hours each day doing this... you will master it. when you see a function in exams, you'll be surprise that differentiating it comes so natural and smooth.

tip: to make the task fun, listen to your iPod while practicing your differentiation. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using wiki (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation/ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration). Numerical solutions gives you the basics in detail and you know how to utilize them in real world. This should clear your confusions. See also the 'see also' sections of these topics.

Answer (score 0):

It kind of depends on which ways you learn math best. If you understand things better when given real life applications, then I suggest Khan Academy, or maybe Brilliant.org, or even Derivatives video on the CrashCourse Youtube channel. But if its easier for you to learn math in the abstract, I suggest Wikibooks or Proofwiki. If you don't know where you fall on the spectrum, I suggest http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/ which will give you a good understanding of how formulas are derived, and it will also give you plenty of example problems which serve as good practice. Also: another great resource is the "Essence of Calculus" playlist on the Youtube channel 3Blue1Brown. Of course you're gonna need some straight-up practice, and for that I suggest the Wolfram Problem Generator. If you get confused on how to do a certian problem, I suggest https://www.derivative-calculator.net/ as its algorithm will give you an entire list of steps for almost every function you plug in.

Have Fun!